# Is it possible to use a JavaScript Value for a min value in a html element?

Tags: javascript

For example if

```
var D1 = D2.val();
```

Is there a way I can use this variable as a minimum in the HTML element such as:

```
<input type = "Date" min="">
```

Answer (score 3):

Give your input an id (i.e. `myinput`) and try :

```
document.getElementById("myinput").setAttribute("min", D1);
```

If you want to get the min value from another date input, you have to use events in order to update the min value of the other input :

```
var dateInputStart = document.getElementById("dateInputStart"),
    dateInput = document.getElementById("dateInput");

dateInputStart.onchange = function(){
    dateInput.setAttribute('min', dateInputStart.value);
};
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ut2fx9zj/)

Comment: Brewal, I have tried you're method. It works when I preset a value, however when I try to get a value from another text box it does not work. I have a link to the JS Fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/mvkvg4hb/20/. Is it possible you could take a look and inform me of any bugs? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yeap it possible:

```
<input type = "number" id='inp' >

var minNumber = 0;
document.getElementById('inp').setAttribute('min', minNumber);
```

The same for Dates and etc.

**[*Fiddle*](http://fiddle.jshell.net/mvkvg4hb/)**

Comment: So instead of the 0, I put in the variable which reads the value from the First Date?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use dot notation to set the attribute:

```
<input id="dateInput" type="date" />

var D1 = '1900-01-01';
document.getElementById("dateInput").min = D1;
```